# Trouble with loops

Tags: c++

I have this simple program to formulate a table of any given number however at the end i want the user to be prompted to either end the program or formulate another table.however the loop does not occur.(i'm only a newbie)

```
int table(){
  int tablenumber;
  int tablecount;
  cout<<"which number's table would you like to print?"<<endl;
  cin>>tablenumber;
  cout<<"till which number would you like to multiply it?"<<endl;
  cin>>tablecount;
  for(int i=0; i<=tablecount; i++){
  cout<<tablenumber<<" X "<<i<<"="<<tablenumber*i<<endl;
  }
}

int main(){
  bool yes=true;
  bool no=false;
  char answer= yes;
while(answer==true){
  table();
  cout<<"would you like to formulate another table?(yes/no)"<<endl;
  cin>>answer;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you put a door in a house and ask if your house equals a specific wooden door?  ;-)

Comment: `while(answer==true){` - you have *nothing* that updates `answer` so how would you expect this to *not* loop forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `answer` is a `char` and you are trying to compare it with a `bool`. `true` and `false` are always zero (false) and any non zero number (true), so once you read info into `answer` the ascii value of the inputted `char` will not be equal to 0 (The int value for false).

Instead read input and loop while `answer` equals yes (Or `y`/`Y`) since `answer` is a `char`. Or make `answer` a `string`:

```
string answer = "yes";
while (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes") {
    //code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. i understood most of that and the code finally works :D

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ transform string lowercase" or "c++ transform string upper case" so you don't have to check for every permutation of case sensitive string.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup on @GBlodgett's answer, I'd like to point out a possible solution:

```
do{
   table();
   cout<<"would you like to formulate another table?(yes/no)"<<endl;
   cin >> answer;
}while(answer == "yes");
```

As you can see, you don't even need those two bools. However, since you want the answer to be "yes", you need to make `answer` a `string`. Good luck!